# how to reverse only one bar in one cell if the value is negative with KableExtra/Formattable/dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, knitr, kableextra, formattable

I have a table and I would like to do an excel bargraph-like ([What I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYOHA.png))
I have a problem with negative values that don't reverse the graph ([what I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bJRF.png)). 
As you can see I have the value -5 that is not reverse and is not proportionnal.
I would like if it is negative I reverse the bar.

my csv database

[csv database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytiFu.png)

my code :

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(formattable)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

dat = read.csv("/dat.csv", header = TRUE, sep =';')

dat[] %>%
  mutate(
    KP1 = color_bar("lightgreen")(KP1),
    KP2 = color_bar("lightgreen")(KP2),
    KP3 = color_bar("lightgreen")(KP3),
    Exposure.1 = color_bar("lightgreen")(Exposure.1),
    Exposure.2 = color_bar("lightgreen")(Exposure.2),
    KP4 = color_bar("lightgreen")(KP4),
    KP5 = color_bar("lightgreen")(KP5)

  ) %>%
  kable("html", escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling("hover", full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(5, width = "10cm") %>%
  column_spec(1,color = 'black', bold = T, border_right = T) %>%
  column_spec(1:5,width = "12.5%") %>%
  row_spec(2,extra_css = "border-top = 10px")
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, you need to write your own color bar function.

```
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

cb <- function(x) {
  range <- max(abs(x))
  width <- round(abs(x / range * 50), 2)
  ifelse(
    x > 0,
    paste0(
      '<span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 2px; ', 
      'padding-right: 2px; background-color: lightgreen; width: ', 
      width, '%; margin-left: 50%; text-align: left;">', x, '</span>'
    ),
    paste0(
      '<span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 2px; ', 
      'padding-right: 2px; background-color: lightpink; width: ', 
      width, '%; margin-right: 50%; text-align: right; float: right; ">', x, '</span>'
    )
  )
}

dt <- data.frame(
  A = 1:10,
  B = -5:4
)

dt %>%
  mutate(
    A = cb(A),
    B = cb(B)
  ) %>%
  kable(escape = F) %>%
  kable_styling("hover", full_width = F) %>%
  column_spec(1:2, width = "3cm") %>%
  row_spec(0, align = "c")
```

[image: example]

Comment: This is excellent, thanks so much for posting this.