# Change bar's color and orientation in a table

Tags: r, kable, kableextra, formattable

I'd like to change side and color of the bar if the number is negative. I was currently using this code but I don't know how to do it.

To better understand what I want, I'd like that Orihuela's bar, whose value is negative, to be red and to the left.

```
increasepob3<-structure(list(CP = c("03009 ", "03014 ", "03031 ", "03065 ", 
"03066 ", "03099 ", "03122 ", "03133 ", "12040 ", "12135 ", "46131 ", 
"46190 ", "46220 ", "46244 ", "46250 "), Municipio = c(" Alcoi", 
" Alacant", " Benidorm", " Elx", " Elda", " Orihuela", " Sant Vicent del Raspeig", 
" Torrevieja", " Castelló de la Plana", " Vila-real", " Gandia", 
" Paterna", " Sagunt", " Torrent", " València"), Evolución = c(0.18, 
3.88, 5.35, 3.54, 0.3, -6.23, 3.82, -11.35, 1.74, 1.79, 1.84, 
4.59, 2.6, 4.69, 1.28)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")

increasepob3$Evolución<- color_bar("lightgreen")(increasepob3$Evolución)

kbl(increasepob3, escape =F, digits = 2) %>%
  kable_paper()
```

[image: PLOT]

Comment: Could you please show us the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO, @Oxford Bicho!

Followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49925194/13249862) to obtain this:

````
---
title: "Use ifelse"
author: "bttomio"
date: "5/9/2021"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(kableExtra)
library(formattable)
library(tidyverse)
```

## R Markdown

```{r kable}
increasepob3<-structure(list(CP = c("03009 ", "03014 ", "03031 ", "03065 ", 
"03066 ", "03099 ", "03122 ", "03133 ", "12040 ", "12135 ", "46131 ", 
"46190 ", "46220 ", "46244 ", "46250 "), Municipio = c(" Alcoi", 
" Alacant", " Benidorm", " Elx", " Elda", " Orihuela", " Sant Vicent del Raspeig", 
" Torrevieja", " Castelló de la Plana", " Vila-real", " Gandia", 
" Paterna", " Sagunt", " Torrent", " València"), Evolución = c(0.18, 
3.88, 5.35, 3.54, 0.3, -6.23, 3.82, -11.35, 1.74, 1.79, 1.84, 
4.59, 2.6, 4.69, 1.28)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")

cb <- function(x) {
  range <- max(abs(x))
  width <- round(abs(x / range * 50), 2)
  ifelse(
    x > 0,
    paste0(
      '<span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 2px; ', 
      'padding-right: 2px; background-color: lightgreen; width: ', 
      width, '%; margin-left: 50%; text-align: left;">', x, '</span>'
    ),
    paste0(
      '<span style="display: inline-block; border-radius: 2px; ', 
      'padding-right: 2px; background-color: lightpink; width: ', 
      width, '%; margin-right: 50%; text-align: right; float: right; ">', x, '</span>'
    )
  )
}

increasepob3 %>%
  mutate(
    Evolución = cb(Evolución)
  ) %>%
  kbl(escape =F, digits = 2) %>%
  kable_paper() 
```
````

-output
[image]

Comment: A lot of thanks, I'd thought something like that, however I don't know how to change bar's direction, I mean, negative bars go to the left, do you have any idea how I can do it?

Comment: I see. Just changed my answer. Please confirm the answer and/or upvote it if it helped you.