# Using kable to color a row of elements based off value

Tags: r, knitr, kable, kableextra

```
knitr::kable(pen_financials_matrix,
             align = c("l", "l", "c", "c", "c", "c"),
             caption = "Financial Report (Sorted by Pen Number)")%>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped")
```

Using this code (see below for the definition of `pen_financials_matrix`) I've created this table:
[image: pic of table]

`pen_financial_matrix` is a data frame that holds columns of values for each pen given. In the picture you can see that there are 9 different pens listed, but this number could change based off the data given.

I am trying to change the text color for certain rows to red or green. For example "Total IOFC" should be  green when greater than 0 and red when less.

I understand how to color columns using `column_spec()` but I don't know how reference values in a row.

```
dput(pen_financials_matrix)
structure(list(Variables = c("Pen Milk Income", "Pen Feed Cost", 
"Feed Efficiency", "Nitrogen Efficiency", "Feed Saved or Wasted", 
"Feed Cost / Cwt of Milk", "Total IOFC"), Units = c("$/day", 
"$/day", "NE Milk / NE Feed,%", "Milk N / Feed N, %", "$/pen/day", 
"(Pen Feed$/Pen milk) * 100", "Milk Income - Feed Cost"), `1` = c("96.48", 
"72", "1.27", "22.88", "0.798", "78.64", "24.48"), `2` = c("3440.41", 
"1672", "1.95", "31.24", "0.761", "51.21", "1768.41"), `3` = c("1199.66", 
"664", "1.71", "26.92", "0.093", "58.33", "535.66"), `4` = c("1638.10", 
"888", "1.75", "29.94", "0.794", "57.12", "750.10"), `5` = c("1155.19", 
"808", "1.36", "24.59", "0.380", "73.71", "347.19"), `7` = c("407.65", 
"312", "1.24", "23.48", "0.505", "80.65", "95.65"), `78` = c("171.45", 
"120", "1.36", "25.10", "0.426", "73.75", "51.45"), `88` = c("763.56", 
"456", "1.59", "27.76", "0.223", "62.93", "307.56"), `98` = c("763.56", 
"456", "1.59", "27.76", "0.223", "62.93", "307.56")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Could you please paste a copy of your data into the question: use `dput(pen_financials_matrix)`.

Comment: Is this helpful to you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50136295/2706569

Comment: @CL the problem with that approach is it doesn't lend itself to a changing table size. It would work if the number of pens was constant, but I believe it won't when it changes.

Comment: @RobertKadlec, does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67455362/13249862?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The central function to use here is [`kableExtra::cell_spec`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html#CellText_Specification), which "is designed to be used before the data.frame gets into the `kable` function". As I could not figure out another way to use this in a "tidy" pipeline, I suggest using the following wrapper function:

```
conditionalColor <- function(x, row, columnOffset, threshold, colorLarger, colorElse) {
  x[row, (columnOffset+1):ncol(x)] <- cell_spec(
    x[row, (columnOffset+1):ncol(x)], 
    color = ifelse(as.numeric(x[row, (columnOffset+1):ncol(x)]) < threshold, 
                   colorLarger, 
                   colorElse))
  return(x)
}
```

This colors the text in all cells of one `row` of `x`, conditional on the cell values being larger (`colorLarger`) than `threshold` or not (`colorElse`), ignoring columns up to `columnOffset`.

Note that `cell_spec` adds markup to the data. Therefore, set `escape = FALSE` in `kable`.

---

**Sample usage** with the object `pen_financials_matrix` as defined in the question: Highlight cells in the row "Total IOFC" (green if > 100, red otherwise):

```
conditionalColor(pen_financials_matrix, 
                 row = which(pen_financials_matrix[ , 1] == "Total IOFC"), 
                 columnOffset = 2, 
                 threshold = 100, colorLarger = "green", colorElse = "red") %>% 
  knitr::kable(escape = FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped")
```

**Output:**

[image: Image of rendered table]

In general, I think this would be easier if the data was transposed such that the variables are in columns instead of rows. Then [more straightforeward solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53341155/2706569) could be feasible.